# Initializing a HashMap with default values?

Tags: java

I'm implementing the A* search algorithm given here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

This line indicates we need to initiliaze a map with the default values of INFINITY,

```
gScore := map with default value of Infinity
```

So I tried that here,

```
Map<State, Double> gScore = new HashMap<State, Double>(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

This does not work however the following does;

```
Map<State, Double> gScore = new HashMap<State, Double>((int) Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

I'm wondering why, and what impact (if any) it will have on my implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to initialize a map with a default value in Java, and your second version will not create a map with a default value of infinity, but instead will try to create an infinitely large map.  (Not really, but it'll try creating the largest map possible.)

Instead, modify the algorithm: anytime you do `map.get(key)`, check if the value is null and, if so, replace it with infinity.

Comment: [Map.getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) is useful for this.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with @Louis that the *best* solution is to check the result of the `get` call to see if it is `null`.

However, it is also *possible* to create a subclass of `HashMap` with an override for the `get` method that returns a default value if `super.get(key)` returns `null`.  But beware of anomalies; e.g.

- Iterating the map will give you only the entries that are "really there".
- If there is a real entry with a `null` value (because you called `put(key, null)`) you won't get a `null` when you call `get` for the entries key.  But but the entry *will* show up in the iteration ... with value `null`.

So, from an OO design perspective, a better approach (to extending `HashMap`) would be to create an application-specific class that only exposes a subset of the `Map` functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of explicitly putting `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` for all the possible keys (which may be inefficient), you can use `putIfAbsent`.

In any place where you have:

```
value = map.get(key);
```

you can change it to:

```
value = map.putIfAbsent(key,Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

This will behave as if the value of any key not present in the `Map` (or any key whose current value is `null`) is `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`. It will put the value `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` in the `Map` for any such keys.

It will save you the need to check if `map.get(key)` returns `null`.